# What is the meaning of alias "@" in GF?

Tags: gf

I have encountered alias sign inside RGL in this operation:

```hs
  mkRoot3 : Str -> Root3 = \fcl -> case fcl of {
      f@? + c@? + l => {f = f ; c = c ; l = l} ;
      _ => error ("mkRoot3: too short root" ++ fcl)
      } ;
```

What does it mean, and what's the use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character @ is used in pattern matching. The expression `foo@bar` means that you match something with the regex `bar`, and bind the result to variable `foo`.

Let's first recap some ways you can pattern match a string without @:

```hs
example1 : Str -> Str = \s -> case s of {
  "x"           => "the string is exactly x" ;
  "x" + _       => "the string starts with x" ;
  ?             => "the string is one character long" ;
  ? + ?         => "the string is two characters long" ;
  ("a"|"i"|"u") => "the string is a vowel" ;
  _             => "whatever, I'm bored"
  } ;
```

In all of these, we are not reusing the string in the right-hand side. If you want to do that, you can just bind it into a variable, like this—not yet using @ , because we are simply matching the start and the end of a string:

```hs
example2 : Str -> Str = \s -> case s of {
  "x" + rest  => "the string starts with x and ends with" ++ rest ;
  start + "x" => "the string starts with" ++ start ++ "and ends with x" ;
  _           => "..." } ;
```

Finally, if you want to match something to a regular expression and use whatever matches the regex on the RHS, now you need to use @:

```hs
example3 : Str -> Str = \s -> case s of {
  v@("a"|"i"|"u") => "the string is the vowel" ++ v ;
  a@?             => "the string is one character long:" ++ a  ;
  a@? + b@?       => "the string is two characters long:" ++ a ++ "followed by" ++ b ;
  _               => "..." } ;
```

If you just tried to match `a + b => …` , or any other pattern that only contains variables, it wouldn't match words that are exactly 2 characters long. Instead it would just match empty string to one of them and the full string to the other.

So matching the regex `?`, which matches exactly one character, and then binding the result to a variable, is the only way you can match something with exact length, and then reuse the matched character/string on the right-hand side.

You can read more on pattern matching at http://www.grammaticalframework.org/doc/gf-refman.html#pattern-matching .